# Resizing a triangle with a scalar value

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems, area

I have came across a really sticky problem here. I am asked to resize a triangle by a given scalar value. (I am given the co-ordinates of the 3 vertices and the center of triangle can easily be evaluated as a result).That would be all.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you multiply all coordinates by a scalar $k$ you resize the triangle. If there are more restrictions that make this solution unacceptable you need to edit your question to tell us what they are.

Comment: @EthanBolker basically I am told to design a program that takes a scalar value and resizes the triangle to a triangle with area k times the area of the original triangle. as long as this condition is met, it should be all good

Comment: If you scale all the coordinates  (hence all the lengths)  by $k$ you scale the area by $k^2$. Now can you figure out how to scale the area by $k$?

Comment: @EthanBolker By multiplying the lengths by square root of k. but I am just lost when it comes to co-ordinates should I just multiply each (x,y) with square root of k?

Comment: That's all you have to do. I suggest drawing a picture of a triangle with simple coordinates and seeing  what happens when $k=4$, doubling all the coordinates.

Comment: @EthanBolker Wow that worked really, thanks alot! how didn't I think of that :D

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question now.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply multiplying the (x,y) co-ordinates of each vertex by square root of the desired scalar value.